# Add logging in Javascript without polluting source code

Tags: javascript, logging, analytics, backbone-events

I want to introduce logging (for analytics) in a web-application without polluting the source code by inserting log statements all over the place. The application is Javascript heavy. In a Java application, we would do something similar by using Aspect-oriented programming and leave the base source code clean. Is it possible to achieve something similar in Javascript?

One approach I am considering currently is to load the logging code separately and have it listen to specific events of interest. Since we are considering using backbone.js, we expect to have a event-driven mechanism which will publish various events. It should then be possible to listen to specific events and log them.

I would like to hear of other approaches/frameworks that developers have tried out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Aspect-oriented programming plugin for jQuery: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-aop/

Comment: Another option is to use the Underscore.js wrap method on a function